# Disable screenshots in Android Studio

Tags: android, ios, iphone, android-studio

I made an android app and I don't want people to take screenshots or record video and was wondering if there was a way to disable screenshots or make them appear blank. Both iOS and Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

In case of android take a look for the Window flag `LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE`. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_SECURE) tells You that after applying this flag to Your window e.g. like this:

```java
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

// or like this

getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

android will:

> treat the content of the window as secure, preventing it from appearing in screenshots or from being viewed on non-secure displays.